# Mapstruct: Map a list inside an object to a list of objects

Tags: java, mapstruct

Given:

```
public class Car {
  private String plate;
  private List<String> tires;
}

public class TirePlate {
  private String plate;
  private String tire;
}
```

I want to map all the Car.tires into individual TirePlates.  I understand that I can make a `List<String>` to `List<tires>` mapper but if I did that I would lose the plate.

How do I get the plate in there?

Comment: Just so I'm getting this right, you're trying to make each individual item in the list Car.tires into a list of TirePlates? Or are you trying to make a hashmap inside a list?

Comment: I'm trying to make each individual item in the list Car.tires into a list of TirePlates?

Comment: What does each string in the Car.tires list look like.

Comment: "1", "2".  etc.  It is just a (obviously) poor example.  If I make a mapping for just the list(String to TirePlate), I loose the "plate" data.  I have to send in the entire Car to map, but I don't think mapstruct will let me do that.

Comment: I think you should just use a simple `for` and run on the `List<String> tires` and populate the new `List<TirePlate>`

Comment: [Related?](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1228)

Comment: so all `TirePlate`s will have the same `plate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to create a custom mapper for the list that would get the `plate` and you would then have a custom method mapping from `plate` and `tire` into a `TirePlate`.

For example:

```
@Mapper
public interface TireMapper {

    CarDto map(Car car);

    default List<TirePlate> map(List<String> tires, String plate) {
        List<TirePlate> tirePlates = new ArrayList<>(tires.size());

        for(String tire: tires) {
            tirePlates.add(map(tire, plate));
        }
        return tirePlates;
    }

    TirePlate map(String tire, String plate);
}
```

Comment: By "custom method" do you mean "custom method that I write?".  So I have to write the map(tire,plate) method?  Also, I think you mean to have return value of the call in the loop to go into the arrayList?

Comment: Yes I mean a customr method for what you need. And yes the custom default method had some compile problems. I've changed it